# What does $$ in this C statement mean

Tags: c

What is the semantic of `$$` in the below statement?

`extern UINT32 Load$$ER_RAM_RO$$Base;`

There is an xml file which is used by the linker that contains the definition as shown below:

`<GlobalVariable Name="Image$$ER_RAM_RO$$Base"   Value="ADDR(STACK_TOP) + 8"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s an identifier character, just like alphanumeric characters and underscores. Allowing `$` in identifiers is [a GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html) to C and C++. You can enable it explicitly with the `-fdollars-in-identifiers` flag. Here it seems to be used in a naming convention where `$$` separates namespace components.

Comment: <>You can enable it explicitly with the -fdollars-in-identifiers flag </>                                                                                                          Not in this example, but is it possible to fill that portion (ER_RAM_RO) by having the linker read the value from an XML file for instance?